# how to pass a variable from a get request into a partial handlebars page

Tags: javascript, session, get, handlebars.js, session-variables

I can get a session variable id from my login and set it to an id, but i am not sure how to pass the variable as the page loads to the handlebars page.

I commented out the res.send I just wanted to see if the emailid would load, which it did. I have looked at some examples, but still unsure how to pass the variable directly into that {{username}} spot in the handlebars/html.

```html
<!--Where the city and state info will be inputted -->
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-sm-3">  
    <form>  
      <p>Search for parking</p>   
      <input id="location-input" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter a location" />
      <br />
      <br />
<!--When Clicked will push all the selected information above to GET API responses -->         
      <button id="submit-button" value="submit">Submit</button>  
    </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div id="test">
        Currently Logged in as: <br /> {{username}}
      </div>
      <br /> 
  </div>
```

```js
// goes to the application folder and checks to see if authenticated
 app.get("/user", application.IsAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
// to help organize, some of the handlebars are within folders   
  var username = req.user.username;
  // res.send(username);
  res.render('./users/user');
 });
```

Comment: You mean `res.render('./users/user', {username: username});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `res.render` second parameter to pass data to the view:

```
res.render('./users/user', { username: username });
```

---

From the [docs](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.render):

### res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])

Renders a `view` and sends the rendered HTML string to the client. Optional parameters:

- locals, an object whose properties define local variables for the
  view.
- callback, a callback function. If provided, the method returns both
  the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an
  automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes
  next(err) internally